# Lsyncd missing updates to small files

Tags: linux, rsync, synchronization

We're experimenting with lsyncd to keep data from server 1 to server 2 in sync.
All seemed to be working fine but we discovered that differences in files start to appear.

We are dealing with processes writing output of jobs to files on disk. These jobs delete any existing output files, then create a new one with the same name to write the output. The size of the output files can range from just a few bytes to 40G.

We came up with the following configuration so that the changes to the output files would be picked up by lsyncd and transferred to the remote server and updated in place, instead of transferring the whole file again and again after each update to the files.

However this update in place seems to bite us in the ass with very small files, where for example only a date would be updated in the first line of the file. The script deletes the file, places the output of the job in a new output file with the same name, and it goes so fast that lsyncd doesn't seem to notice it.

Anybody here can help me figure this out?

This is the current running config. We are currently running with 4 input dirs to speed things up a bit because of the amount of data we're dealing with.

```
settings {
   logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
   statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status",
   statusInterval = 1,
   nodaemon   = false,
   inotifyMode = "CloseWrite or Modify",
   insist = true
}
dirs = {
    '/data/dir1',
    '/data/dir2',
    '/data/dir3',
    '/data/dir4',
}
for _, directory in ipairs( dirs )
do
sync {
        default.rsyncssh,
        source = directory,
        targetdir = directory,
        host = "remote_host",
        delay = 0,
        rsync = {
            compress = false,
            whole_file = false,
            update = true,
            inplace = true,
            checksum = true,
            owner = true,
            archive = true,
            perms = true,
            group = true,
            xattrs = true,
            _extra = { "--append-verify" },
            rsh = "/usr/bin/ssh -q -l lsyncd_ssh_user -i /home/lsyncd_ssh_user/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o User=lsyncd_ssh_user"
        },
}
end
```